# Keyboard Shortcuts Don't Work Properly After 14.04 -> 16.04 Upgrade

Tags: shortcut-keys, 16.04

I recently did an upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04 and after the upgrade keyboard shortcuts stopped working. Not just ones I set, but all of them. After investigating/messing around a little bit I figured out it appears that the shortcuts are only responsive to upper-case letters.... So if I have caps lock on they work, otherwise they don't.

I've tried changing the shortcuts via the Settings Manager and I tried using dconf editor to reset the defaults but that didn't work. I also saw some recommendations to delete the .gconf directory, however I don't see anything in that directory that's relevant. I installed 16.04 in a VM on another machine and didn't see this issue so it's likely an artifact from the upgrade, but I'm not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knowing it was a configuration problem I decided to just start deleting configuration files. I'm not sure exactly which one it was that fixed it (I probably should have deleted one at a time to figure that out...), but I deleted:

~/.cache
~/.compiz
~/.config
~/.gconf
~/.gnome*
~/.kde

and keyboard shortcuts work again after a reboot without needing caps lock on...

Comment: I got workspace-switching with C-A-arrow back by `mv .config .back-config`.  This was after compiz and/or unity had crashed, 16.04 (upgraded some time ago from 14.04).

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem upgrading from 15.04 to 16.04 I worked around it by using compiz settings manager to add commands with identical bindings. 
ie. 
/usr/bin/gnome-terminal -> ctrl + alt + t

I found that it was generally isolated to shortcuts that were launching programs in my case.

On 15.04 - I was able to resolve it by removing the package appmenu-qt5

```
apt remove appmenu-qt5
```

Previously this didn't help for 16.04 but now its working fine

I realise this isn't a perfect solution but I hope it is helpful

Comment: @vassago I tried individually deleting config files to try and help narrow it down for other people who might have a similar issue but it seems that we might have slightly different issues (would have commented on your answer but unfortunately don't have the rep yet on Ask Ubuntu)

Comment: Its now working for Ubuntu as well

Answer (score 0):

another workaround: use the international keyboards with dead keys. 
That works for me, although the dead keys are quite annoying.
Or better, use the international keyboard with altGr dead keys.

I tried creating a new user on my machine, or removing the given ~/.xxx dirs, but that did not help.

Comment: How is using a different keyboard layout better than having to push caps lock? The solution sounds to be worse than the initial problem.

Comment: if the keyboard layout matches your keyboard, then everything works as usual. If you have to type caps-lock (which did not work for me, although I think it worked occasionally), you have to do an extra thing: turn caps-lock on, type shortcut, turn caps-lock off. So choosing international keyboard layout is way better.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. The Nav keyboard shortcuts just stop working.

I narrowed it down to `Home/.config/dconf/user`
This is a binary settings file.

I just renamed it `user` to `_user`

You will lose some settings, like any custom app luncher shortcuts but the keyboard shortcuts should work again.

Hope this save some else some time.

---

### warning - advanced

FYI: You can edit this binary file with dconf-editor from the `dconf-tools` package, which is the equivalent to `gconf-editor`.

To install it, do this command

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Answer (score 0):

Open CompizConfig Settings Manager, find "Commands" plugin, uncheck it, wait couple seconds and check it back. After that all keyboards shortcuts works again